# Heater with NiCr

Tags: arduino, batteries, mosfet

[image]

I'm trying to build a little circuit to heat a stainless steel needle. In order to do that, I'm using a MOSFET, four AAA batteries and an Arduino for controlling the heating through PWM, as illustrated in the image below. NiCr actually is coiled around the needle. The circuit works and NiCr heats up and its temperature reaches something around 40ºC or even more, but it seems that absolutely nothing happens to the needle, its temperature doesn't get increased. I wonder if there is another way to heat the needle, because using NiCr coiled around it isn't working.

Comment: I'm absolutely sure that the needle will get warmer. The other problem is that your cartoon circuit won't power the arduino.

Comment: It may be that the needle is shorting the current past the coil. Are you certain that the coil is getting warm, or might it only be the wire leading to the coil? .

Comment: RF induction method works for experts but why does it need to get hot> How about epoxy to ceramic resistor?

Comment: @user12707: Fritzing should be able to generate a schematic diagram for you instead of the wiring schematic. The schematic will show us the pinout and function of the transistor, etc. Your wiring diagram doesn't.

Comment: @Andyaka I fixed that.

Comment: @bitsmack. The coil is getting warm for sure, but not the needle.

Comment: @Transistor Many thanks for ur tip. The schematic diagram was generated and replaced the former figure.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 The problem regarding RF induction is that it requires many more components. It would be interesting that the circuit have as minimal components as possible.

Comment: It appears to me the only problem is heat transfer. Air is an insulator

Comment: connect the needle directly to the battery, It'll get hot. stainless steel is good like that.

Answer (score 0):

Your diagram looks like spaghetti to me but if you do below you will certainly create some heat. How much will depend on your Rds(on) of the FET and coil resistance. You have not stated what FET your using so if its small it will die of heat, if its big (high current rating) it may need more gate charge so use a pull down from Vcc and pull the digital pin low to turn it off.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgfn8s.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: The mosfet I'm using is IRL3705Z.